# multiple Tor instances through stem

Tags: python-3.x, tor, stem

I am developing a script that creates 3 Tor instances using stem, from stem tutorial "to Russia with love".

```
def print_bootstrap_lines(line):
  if "Bootstrapped " in line:
    print(term.format(line, term.Color.BLUE))

def main():
        SocksPort=9050
        #print(str(SocksPort))
        i=0
        while i<2:
                tor_process=stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
                config={
                'SocksPort':str(SocksPort),
                'ControlPort':str(SocksPort+1),
                'ExitNodes':'{ru}',
                'StrictNodes':'1',},
                init_msg_handler=print_bootstrap_lines,
                )
                SocksPort=SocksPort+2
                i=i+1
```

after the creation of the first instance, a return error is printed:

```
OSError: Process terminated: No, it's still there.  Exiting.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

launch_tor_with_config() function does launch tor with a temporary new torrc file which gets deleted once the tor instance is killed/stopped.
but i noticed that there is a lock file, like the one you have when you interrupt the Linux package manager updates, but it is located in 
`~/.tor/lck` 
so before starting the new instance make sure to wait for the lock file to appear, then delete it from within your script, and the multiple tor instances will be created successfully.

Answer (score 0):

just set "DataDirettory" different for each thread.

```
self.tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
                          config={
                               'SocksPort':str(self.SocksPort),
                               'ControlPort':str(self.ControlPort),
                               'ExitNodes':self.ExitNodes,
                               'StrictNodes':self.StrictNodes,
                               'DataDirectory': path,
                               'Log': [
                                      'NOTICE stdout',
                                      'ERR file /tmp/tor_error_log',
                               ],
                          },
                          #init_msg_handler=self.print_bootstrap_lines(),
                          )
```

Answer (score 0):

just add any data directory like what a friend (lacopoOrtis) has written in above answer

make sure you have installed stem by using this command in terminal:

```
pip install stem
```

and you have imported it in your py file like this

```
import stem.process
```

path in 'DataDirectory' can be any path like c:/datadirectories/1/